# why doesn't NodeJS support String.prototype.replaceAll?

Tags: node.js, v8

This string method exists in browserland, but not in Node. Why not? It's neither brand-new nor exotic.

- replaceAll is part of ECMA-262 [<sup>src</sup>](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.replaceall)
- replaceAll is described in detail on the V8 blog (added in v8.1) [<sup>src</sup>](https://v8.dev/features/string-replaceall)
- NodeJS upgraded to V8 v8.1 with NodeJS v14.0 [<sup>src</sup>](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.0.0/#update-to-v8-8-1)

And yet:

```sh
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v14.13.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> 'asdf'.replaceAll
undefined
```

I'm not asking for polyfills; I can do a regex or loop over single-instance `replace`. I'm trying to figure out why this seemingly unremarkable feature doesn't exist in NodeJS, even though it seems to be available in just about every other JS environment, and even though all the docs suggest to me that it should exist.

Comment: It's in nodejs v15.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V15.md#v8-86---35415

Comment: I suspect that once there was a hardcore Node dev who thought that `replace(/foo/g, text)` is so elegant that nobody needs the poor `replaceAll`. However, I like the robust `replaceAll`, mind its big old fat... All.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Nodejs v14 has V8 8.4  But, replaceAll was added to V8 8.5.  Nodejs v15 has V8 8.6 and thus that's the first nodejs version where you can use `.replaceAll()`.  You can see this all described in the nodejs v15 [release notes](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V15.md#15.0.0) or in this specific [change report](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/35415).

Comment: I'm not sure why I interpreted that V8 blog post to say that replaceAll was implemented in V8 v8.1. In any case, this is the paper trail I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: My server at Render.com says `Detected Node version 17.4.0` but then also throws `TypeError: (0 , crypto__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.randomUUID)(...).replaceAll is not a function`, so I'm really confused.

Comment: @Ryan - I'd suggest you post your own question with your own specifics.  The node version that `.replaceAll()` exist in is clear so your situation must involve something beyond that and your own question would need to describe your environment and configuration (particularly what webpack is being used for and how its configured).  Comments on this question are probably not the right place to explore that.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to just use `replace()` (the old version) rather than try to figure all of that out. Thanks though!

Comment: Here is a +1 and I've asked my question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/72637010/470749 Thanks.