# `replaceAll` is not working in Next.js (Node.js) when deployed to Render.com server

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

My code all works locally (running Node 17.4.0).

But as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66937529/why-doesnt-nodejs-support-string-prototype-replaceall#comment125612221_66937599), when I deploy to my production server at Render.com, which says `Detected Node version 17.4.0` (which is the same version that I use for local development), functions throw errors like:

- `TypeError: (0 , crypto__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.randomUUID)(...).replaceAll is not a function`.
- `TypeError: (intermediate value).format(...).replaceAll is not a function    at getShortLocalizedDate`

How can I ensure that `replaceAll` can work on my production server?

P.S. I think Node has supported `replaceAll` since [v15](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V15.md#15.0.0).

Comment: Really, they have version `17.x.x` in a production environment? That seems to be rather strange, as from the node developers all odd major versions are considered development versions and not for use in production environment.

Comment: What are are the values that `.replaceAll` is called on and where the method doesn't exist? Is it something that's not a string?

Comment: @derpirscher I was a bit surprised by that too.

Comment: @VLAZ strings. For example, the result of `randomUUID()`. (`import { randomUUID } from 'crypto'; // Added in: node v14.17.0`)

Comment: @VLAZ another example: `const dateTimeStr = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
    dateStyle: 'short',
    timeStyle: 'short',
  })
    .format(dateTime)
    .replaceAll(',', '');`

Comment: Then the only logical conclusion for me is that the server is *not* running your application with Node 17. It might have it installed but it might be executing your application with a lower version.

Comment: looking at the docs at [render.com](https://render.com/docs/node-version) it says *"By default, Render uses Node version 14.17.0"* They *might* be outdated, but that's the first document I came across on searching for "render.com node version" I don't know, what you use to detect your node version, but it might be worth, checking that ...

Comment: And also version 14.x. seems more logical to me, as this is in fact an (older but still under maintenance for nearly a year) LTS release

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for your help! I got it working and posted my notes below.

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks for your help! I got it working and posted my notes below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some things to check: Do you maybe have something else overriding the Node version set in `engines.node`? According to https://render.com/docs/node-version, the `engines.node` value will be overridden by

1. A `NODE_VERSION` environment variable
2. A `.node-version` file at the root of your repo
3. A `.nvmrc` file at the root of your repo.

Also, when you deploy on Render, are you selecting Node as the **Environment**?

Here's a small test deploy to Render I created to verify that odd Node version numbers work on Render and also to verify that `replaceAll()` works in Node v17.4.0.

**Code** (also at https://github.com/crcastle/test-replaceall)

`server.js`:

```js
const http = require('http')


const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  const orig = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?';

  const monkey = orig.replaceAll('dog', 'monkey');
  // expected output: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy monkey. If the monkey reacted, was it really lazy?"
  
  // global flag required when calling replaceAll with regex
  const regex = /Dog/ig;
  const ferret = orig.replaceAll(regex, 'ferret');
  // expected output: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the ferret reacted, was it really lazy?"

  const version = process.version;

  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(`Original: ${orig}\nMonkey: ${monkey}\nFerret: ${ferret}\nI am Node version ${version}`);
};

const HOST = "0.0.0.0";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 10000;
const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "test-replaceall",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "17.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Output** (also temporarily deployed to https://test-replaceall.onrender.com)

```
Original: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?
Monkey: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy monkey. If the monkey reacted, was it really lazy?
Ferret: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the ferret reacted, was it really lazy?
I am Node version v17.4.0
```

**Build and deploy log**

```
Jun 15 04:07:08 PM  ==> Cloning from https://github.com/crcastle/test-replaceall...
Jun 15 04:07:09 PM  ==> Checking out commit 17972cbecfdeafc0eb1c4a09cad07400ab5c8bc1 in branch main
Jun 15 04:07:25 PM  ==> Detected Node version 17.4.0
Jun 15 04:07:26 PM  ==> Running build command 'npm i'...
Jun 15 04:07:27 PM  up to date, audited 1 package in 297ms
Jun 15 04:07:27 PM  found 0 vulnerabilities
Jun 15 04:07:43 PM  ==> Uploading build...
Jun 15 04:07:49 PM  ==> Build successful 
Jun 15 04:07:49 PM  ==> Deploying...
Jun 15 04:08:25 PM  ==> Detected Node version 17.4.0
Jun 15 04:08:25 PM  ==> Starting service with 'node server.js'
Jun 15 04:08:25 PM  Server is listening on http://0.0.0.0:10000
```

Comment: I'm very impressed with your answer! I'll go ahead and accept it even though I'm even more confused since it seems to refute my guesses in my answer. I had no `.nvmrc` file but had the other options all set to the same Node version.

Comment: Just as a hint, if you are replacing with regex, you don't need `replaceAll`, but with the `/g` flag `replace` also works, and always did. Ie `"astring".replaceAll(/a/g, "b")` is equivalent to `"astring".replace(/a/g, "b")` ...

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks. Yeah, I know of workarounds for not using `replaceAll`, but it was bugging me (and feeling risky) that my production server was behaving differently from my local one. I still don't understand why it's now working, but at least it is.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that @derpirscher! I copied the `replaceAll` code from MDN here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll, but what you say makes total sense.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks. If you have a repo and deploy instructions you can share that demonstrates the strange behavior you're seeing, I'm happy to dig into it a bit more!

Answer (score 0):

https://render.com/docs/node-version seems incomplete.

I wonder if Render ignores odd-numbered Node versions.

I'd specified 17.4.0 in the environment variables and also in `package.json`, but then I'd still see the deployment log say "Detected Node version 18.3.0", and then `replaceAll` inexplicably still wouldn't work.

More recently I've specified `NODE_VERSION=18.3.0` in the environment variables, and I've even added to `package.json`: `"engines": { "node": ">=18.3.0 <19" },`. The latest deployment log at https://dashboard.render.com/web/srv-caevvv7ho1kse31neb0g/deploys/dep-cal3r7vh8vl4d0g8vujg again said:
`Jun 15 04:16:34 PM  ==> Detected Node version 18.3.0`.

And this time `replaceAll` works!

So my interpretation is:

1. The `Detected Node version ___` shown in deployment logs cannot be relied upon.
2. Specifying a Node version using methods at https://render.com/docs/node-version might not work unless their major version number is even (such as 18).

It's mysterious. But I'm glad my code is working now!

Comment: You can use `process.version` in your app, the detect the version of the runtime runnig your app